# Rack::Deflater and Rack::URLMap

Tags: ruby, rack

I would like to conditionally enable `Rack::Deflater` based on the size of the response body, like so:

```
use Rack::Deflater, :if => lambda { |*, body| body.map(&:bytesize).reduce(0, :+) > 512 }
```

If I insert the `Rack::Deflater` middleware inside one of my Rack applications, this lambda works fine; `body` is an array of strings. However, if I insert the `Rack::Deflater` middleware before `Rack::URLMap` (in `config.ru`), it does not; because `body` is now a `Rack::BodyProxy` object.

I've looked into the `Rack::BodyProxy` definition and it seems a bit opaque. There isn't a clear way to resolve the actual body from this object; `body.body` returns `nil`. What's the easiest/best way determine the response body size in this situation, short of moving the `Rack::Deflater` middleware down into each of my Rack applications?

**tl;dr**: How can I determine the size of the response body given a `Rack::BodyProxy` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Rack::BodyProxy` does provide an `#each` method as a workaround of issue [rack/rack#434](https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/434). This method returns an enumerator over the elements of the private `@body` ivar. Adding an `.each` into the call chain resolves this problem for `Rack::BodyProxy` objects, and it's a no-op for more ordinary array-based bodies, so for now this gets me where I need to be. However, I would still like to understand why I'm getting these objects and if there's a better way to deal with them.

Here's the modified and working solution:

```
use Rack::Deflater, :if => lambda { |*, body| 
  body.each.map(&:bytesize).reduce(0, :+) > 512 
}
```

**UPDATE:** Hrrm, sometimes `body` is a `Rack::BodyProxy` object, and `body.body` is a `Rack::Response` object. This is getting a little out of hand...! Here's the solution I'm using now:

```
use Rack::Deflater, :if => lambda { |*, body|
  body.map(&:bytesize).reduce(0, :+) > 512 \
    if body.respond_to?(:map) \
    or body.respond_to?(:each) and (body = body.each).respond_to?(:map)
}
```

Far from elegant...